# Xcode Editor PlaceHolder in source file

Tags: swift, xcode

This is my code:

`import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var activePlayer = 1 //Cross


    @IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if (activePlayer == 1)
        {
```

//I always get an error around this part

sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Cross.png"), for: UIControl.State())
            }
            else
            {
                 sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Nought.png"), for: UIControl.State())
            }
        }

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

` Somebody please help me because I need to know.,
If it would be of help, I have inserted "Cross.png" into the project and inserted "Nought.png", but when why was writing that part of the code, It never reccomended me to put those names like as a suggestion.

Comment: Whenever you have a question about an error, be sure to **include the text of the error** in you post.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put the images in the Assets.xcassets folder. Then you will get the suggestions.

If that doesn't work make sure to save images in the Assets.xcassets folder and set image like:

ImageView.image = image

When you type in image, click on the suggestion which says image literal and double click on the picture icon. You should get access to all the images in the Assets.xcassets folder.